# Read Cassandra is always taking 60 sec. Why? (cassandra ,thrift,php)

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift

While I am retrieving data from Cassandra using Thrift and PHP, it always takes 60 seconds. Why?

Comment: It sounds like something is timing out then allowing the code to read the data. This question needs more information.

Comment: Sounds like a riddle. To get to the other side?

Comment: Your Turbo Encabulator needs to be replaced. That's my best guess.

Answer (score 5):

I got it.

There were two entries in my files

```
$this->socket->setRecvTimeout(60000);
$this->socket->setSendTimeout(60000);
```

I have removed them and it's working fine

Comment: Good job. Thanks for posting the answer as well so others with the same problem may be helped by it.